# How to get list of object from flowable object using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have got 2 data classes:

**GitResult**

```
data class GitResult (

    @SerializedName("total_count")
    @Expose
    var total_count: Int,

    @SerializedName("incomplete_results")
    @Expose
    var incomplete_results: Boolean,

    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    var items: MutableList<ItemList>
){}
```

and **ItemList**

```
data class ItemList (

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int,

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String,

    @SerializedName("language")
    @Expose
    var language: String?,

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    var description: String?,

    @SerializedName("html_url")
    @Expose
    var html_url: String?
){}
```

with retrofit I make a call:

```
 @GET("repositories")
    fun getAllRepo2(@Query("q") q: String? ,
                   @Query("sort") sort: String? ,
                   @Query("order") order: String?
    ) : Observable<GitResult>
```

then return it to my viewModel class as Flowable object.

```
 val ResultFromApiCall_flowable =  mainRepository.fetchToDosFromServer(filterDate, filterStatus, filterName)
```

So, now I have a flowable object of **GitResult**. But how do I get the list of **ItemList** objects using both RxJava .

I tried using **map** operator:

```
    var lst = mutableListOf<ItemList>()

    var yy = ResultFromApiCall_flowable.map {//it = gitResult
            gitResult ->

            gitResult.items.forEach {
               lst.add(it)
            }
         lst

    } // returns Observable<MutableList<ItemList>>


     yy.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe { //it:MutableList<ItemList>

        object: Observer<MutableList<ItemList>>{
        override fun onComplete() {
            Log.d("myLog","------------test3 ")
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}


        override fun onError(e: Throwable) { }

        override fun onNext(t: MutableList<ItemList>) {
            Log.d("myLog","------------test3 $t")
        }


    }}
```

But seems that its not working. How do i solve it?

Comment: attach your error log here

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the network call on main thread change the`subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`
so

```java
 yy.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe { //it:MutableList<ItemList>

        object: Observer<MutableList<ItemList>>{
        override fun onComplete() {
            Log.d("myLog","------------test3 ")
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}


        override fun onError(e: Throwable) { }

        override fun onNext(t: MutableList<ItemList>) {
            Log.d("myLog","------------test3 $t")
        }


    }}
```